# convert string to arraylist <Character> in java

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist, converters

How to convert a String without separator to an `ArrayList<Character>`.

My String is like this:

```
String str = "abcd..."
```

I know one way of doing this is converting the String to `char[]` first, and then convert the `char []` to `ArrayList <Character>`.

Is there any better way to do this? like converting directly? Considering time and performance, because I am coding with a big database.

Comment: So...do you want to take the implicit string and convert each character in it to a collection of some sort?  If that's the case, what have you tried?  Some sample code would be beneficial.

Comment: Do you really want to convert to `ArrayList` or just wrap string into `List` backed by the original string?

Comment: @Makoto I have tried 'char [] chars = str.toCharArray (); ArrayList <Character> mylist = new ArrayList <Character> (); for (char c : chars) mylist.add (c);'

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov I really want to convert it to ArrayList

Comment: @squiguy As I mentioned below, your code seems not working.

Answer (score 20):

You need to add it like this.

```
String str = "abcd...";
ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>();
for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
  chars.add(c);
}
```

Comment: Well. I don't think it works. str.toCharArray () will return char [], while you are assigning it to an ArrayList with type Character. To be more precise, you cannot convert an array of primitives to an ArrayList like this.

Comment: This should work :), but as I mentioned, you converted the string to a  char array first, and then added it one by one to get the ArrayList. I am considering the space and time costs while the string is very large and the number of strings is also huge in a database.

Comment: @aga_pan Hmm, well unless you venture off into some third party libraries, I am not sure there is a way around it.  Beats me at least!

Comment: @aga_pan In the end, the efficiency of a loop to compiled byte code will be optimized by the virtual machine I am sure.  The only way to find out would be to choose some methods and play around with it.

Answer (score 7):

Sorry for the Retrobump, but this is now really easy!

You can do this easily in Java 8 using Streams! Try this:

```
String string = "testingString";
List<Character> list = string.chars().mapToObj((i) -> Character.valueOf((char)i)).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(list);
```

You need to use `mapToObj` because `chars()` returns an `IntStream`.

Comment: Error:(13, 114) java: incompatible types: inference variable R has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: java.util.List<java.lang.Character>
    upper bounds: java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.Character>,java.lang.Object

Answer (score 7):

use lambda expression to do this.

```
String big_data = "big-data";
ArrayList<Character> chars
        = new ArrayList<>(
                 big_data.chars()
                .mapToObj(e -> (char) e)
                .collect(
                        Collectors.toList()
                )
        );
```

Answer (score 5):

If you dn not need to modify list after it created, probably the better way would be to wrap string into class implementing `List<Character>` interface like this:

```
import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.List;

public class StringCharacterList extends AbstractList <Character>
{
    private final String string;

    public StringCharacterList (String string)
    {
        this.string = string;
    }

    @Override
    public Character get (int index)
    {
        return Character.valueOf (string.charAt (index));
    }

    @Override
    public int size ()
    {
        return string.length ();
    }
}
```

And then use this class like this:

```
List <Character> l = new StringCharacterList ("Hello, World!");
System.out.println (l);
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I need is an ArrayList :)

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String str = "abcd...";
        ArrayList<Character> a=new ArrayList<Character>();
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
        {
            a.add(str.charAt(i));

        }
        System.out.println(a);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class YourClass{

    public static void main(String [] args){

        ArrayList<Character> char = new ArrayList<Character>();
        String str = "abcd...";

        for (int x = 0; x < str.length(); x ++){
            char.add(str.charAt(x));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String myString = "xxx";
ArrayList<Character> myArrayList = myString.chars().mapToObj(x -> (char) x).collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));
myArrayList.forEach(System.out::println);
```